# How to iterate json array from role.json is role to chef recipe

Tags: json, chef-infra, ruby-hash

I have a `role_multi_module.json` which is a chef role which contains a array in JSON format.

Role name: role_multi_module.json

```json
{
    "name": "role_multi_module",
    "default_attributes": {
            "cloud": {
                    "global": false
            }
    },
    "override_attributes": {},
    "json_class": "Chef::Role",
    "description": "This is just a test role, no big deal.",
    "employees": [{
                    "name": "Ram",
                    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
                    "age": 23
            },
            {
                    "name": "Shyam",
                    "email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
                    "age": 28
            }
    ],
    "chef_type": "role",
    "run_list": ["recipe[hello-chef]"]
}
```

Using the below recipe I'm able to get only one employee details i.e. the second one.

Recipe name: multi.rb

```rb
execute 'test-multi-module' do  
  node['role_multi_module']['employees'].each do |employee|
    command "echo #{employees['name']} #{employees['email']}}"
  end
end
```

How to iterate the JSON array of 2 employees from the above recipe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation on [roles](https://docs.chef.io/roles/), there are some fixed allowed fields such as `name`, `description`, etc. User defined variables should be defined under `default_attributes` or `override_attributes`.

A role structure like this:

```json
  "default_attributes": {
    "employees": [
      {
        "name": "Ram",
        "email": "ram@gmail.com",
        "age": 23
      },
      {
        "name": "Shyam",
        "email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
        "age": 28
      }
    ],
    "cloud": {
      "global": false
    }
  },
```

> How to iterate the JSON array of 2 employees from the above recipe?

We need to iterate the entire `execute` resource (not just `command`) for each item of `employee` array. Considering the above JSON declaration:

```rb
node['employees'].each do |employee|
  execute "test-multi-#{employee['name']}" do
    command "echo #{employee['name']} #{employee['email']}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Seshadri, thanks. I will test and update you.

Comment: Hi Seshadri, your resolution is very helpful and executing successfully, I have added the employees to default_attributes. and the your above recipe is success with the output, below. * execute[test-multi-Ram] action run - execute echo Ram ram@gmail.com * execute[test-multi-Shyam] action run - execute echo Shyam shyam23@gmail.com Thanks a lot for your time. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know to know you found this useful!

Comment: Hi seshadri_c,

Please help on followup on the bellow issue.
```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617416/chef-recipe-compile-error-as-undefined-method-cwd-for-cookbook
```
Thanks