# chef recipe compile error as "undefined method 'cwd' for cookbook"

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef recipe to iterate multi module from json array.

Here i have defined the cwd from the json node attribute, but it is getting failed with the chef recipe compile error as "undefined method 'cwd' for cookbook".

Becuase in the devops_dir/scripts we are having the shell script to call and execute for each iteration of module in the json Array(modules).

Please correct me.

role name: role.json

```
{
    "name": "role_multi_module",
    "default_attributes": {
        "employees": [{
                "name": "Ram",
                "email": "ram@gmail.com",
                "age": 23
            },
            {
                "name": "Shyam",
                "email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
                "age": 28
            }
        ],
        "cloud": {
            "global": false
        },
        "devops_dir": "/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello-chef/recipes",
        "user": "ec2-user",
        "group": "ec2-user"
    },
    "override_attributes": {},
    "json_class": "Chef::Role",
    "description": "This is just a test role, no big deal.",
    "chef_type": "role",
    "run_list": ["recipe[multi-module]"]
}
```

Chef recipe: multi-module.rb

```
node['employees'].each do |employee|
  execute "test-multi-#{employee['name']}" do
    cwd "#{node['devops_dir']}/scripts/"
    user node['user']
    group node['group']
    command "bash shell.sh #{employee['name']} #{employee['email']}"
  end
end
```

shell.sh and directory (/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello-chef/recipes/scripts)

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-95-251 scripts]$ pwd
/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello-chef/recipes/scripts
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-95-251 scripts]$ ll
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 61 Sep  6 09:18 shell.sh
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-95-251 scripts]$ cat shell.sh
name=$1
email=$2
echo "Print Name: $name and Email: $email"
```

devops_dir is existed but the shell script is not running from the above recipe logic.
I have a doubt will the node variables like devops_url execute inside the modules (arrays).?

Comment: Does the run fail? Can you show the relevant output of chef-client?

Comment: Hi Seshadri,
its working fine, successfully.
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hi Seshadri
i have one more thing to duscuss, the problem here is the command is not working for the bash or python scripts are not unning.

Thanks & Regards,
Syam

Comment: if i use live_stream true in execute block i can see the o/p as below 
    [execute] Print Name: Ram and Email: ram@gmail.com
if not i can see
    - execute bash shell.sh Shyam shyam23@gmail.com

Comment: The default behaviour or `execute` is not to show the stdout. It will just run and report as success or failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because `cwd` is a property of [execute resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/), and it should be within that block. Same is the case with `user` and `group`.

Also, when we specify attributes/variables from role, we don't need to specify `node['role']` prefix. We can directly access `node['devops_dir']`, etc.

So your code modified as below should work fine:

```rb
node['employees'].each do |employee|
  execute "test-multi-#{employee['name']}" do
    command "bash python.sh #{employee['name']} #{employee['email']}"
    cwd "#{node['devops_dir']}/scripts"
    user node['user']
    group node['group']
  end
end
```

Comment: still it is not calling the script in the directory "/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello-chef/recipes/script"
I have used your above logic.

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-95-251 scripts]$ cat shell.sh
name=$1
email=$2
echo "Print Name: $name and Email: $email"

Comment: The `cwd` points to `/home/ec2-user/scripts/` (based on `devops_dir`. You are expecting in a different path.

Comment: yes i have updated accordingly in the role.
"devops_dir": "/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/hello-chef/recipes"

Comment: The `execute` runs on the node, and the file should be on the node, if you are expecting to run a file present on Chef server, it won't work.

Comment: no, im trying to run the script on the node only

Comment: Please update the question with the latest changes, and also what do you mean that the script isn't running?